# Removing items on click based on checkbox status using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using [this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DBjpHF4X0B8uq5emhayJ?p=preview). It displays a list of products. When I click on remove button, the items which are checked should be removed from the list.

```
<button ng-click="onClick()" class="k-button">Remove</button>
```

I have tried various things however, nothing is working. I am not exactly getting what logic should go in the following logic

```
$scope.onClick = function () {

            }
```

I know it is something very simple however, I am not able to get it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your plunkr is not working

Comment: Its working here, I also opened it on other browser. It only displays the list of items and I need to remove the items which are checked on click.

Comment: Take a look here

http://www.telerik.com/forums/bulk-delete-of-selected-items

Answer (score 0):

If you ask about logic, i will try to explain it here..

First inside `onClick` function get your gird's datasource variable, then find all selected checkboxes and use jquery `each` to iterate over each checkbox and find closest `data-uid` attribute. Every grid row has `uid` in its DOM, with this `uid` value get kendo observable object from datasource with `getByUid` method.
Last using datasource pass this observable object to `remove` method of datasource.

This is [Kendo datasource API](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource), hopes it helps you to write the code..